# Designing a different kind of tag cloud

Tags: php, html, css, tags, knapsack-problem

Rather than having a bunch of links that are all different sizes, I want all of my tags to be the same size. However, my goal is to minimize the amount of space required to make the cloud, aka minimizing the number of lines used.

Take this example:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [stevethomas.com.au](https://stevethomas.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/tagcloud1.gif))</sub>

Looks like any normal tag cloud. However, look at all that extra space around the 'roughdiamond' tag, which could be filled in by other tags like 'stone' down near the bottom, which could effectively eliminate an entire extra line from the cloud.

How would I go about getting the words to fill in whatever space possible above them before starting a new line? I'm not talking about reorganizing them to find the absolute minimum number of lines required. If I was going through the list in the image, 'pendant', 'howlite', and 'igrice' would go to line 1 filling it up, 'roughdiamond' would go to line 2 because line 1 is full, 'tourmaline' would go to line 3 because it can't fit on lines 1 or 2, same with 'emberald', but 'pearl' would go to line 2 because it can fit there since there is extra space. I figure there would probably be some way of doing this in CSS that would simply cause the links to collapse into any fillable space it can fit in to.

Comment: You could put them all into a backpack...

Comment: Yup, I smell a knapsack problem. Have fun.

Comment: Does anyone actually use tag clouds?  I find them to be quite annoying myself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt this is possible in CSS since this requires specific computations to rearrange the words optimally.

The problem you are actually looking to tackle is the 2 dimensional [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing) problem with bins of equal size and items of variable size.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/algorithm-needed-for-packing-rectangles-in-a-fairly-optimal-way/1213571#1213571) to a question about bin packing, sorting your items from largest to smallest and then fitting smaller words in between the large ones will usually result in a fairly good approximation.  You will have to try it out with the types of words you'll be using to find out whether this will work for you (his approach may result in many small words grouped at the bottom of your cloud).

Comment: I don't quite understand those last couple of lines. Most of the time my tag clouds will be 10 tags or less, which is why I'm trying to reduce the number of lines they use. I don't really want 10 tags using up 10 lines and only using about 50% of the space on those lines.

Comment: @animuson: 10 tags using only 50% of the space would only occupy 5 lines, for 10 tags to occupy 10 lines each tag would have to be wider than 50% and thus impossible to optimize.

Comment: @animuson: what I meant was you should probably look into solving the general problem of fitting the words into the smallest space possible (not just moving individual words up in the list if possible which may be harder).    I am adding an edit now referencing the bin packing problem which actually what you are looking for.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Sorry, I didn't mention that my current method just puts a tag on its own line. So If I had 10 tags it would use 10 lines. I don't have any sort of tag cloud method in use at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an optimal solution but will probably (most of the time) be way better than a random one and way faster than a optimal one: **display each tag by string <s>length</s> width in descending order**.

This will give you a arrangement that will be at max, 14% worse than the optimal solution.

**EDIT:** Also works if you sort tags by <s>strlen</s> width in ascending order.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this as well, but didn't feel like doing the math to see if it would be efficient.

Comment: @animuson: There are Java and Flash based *tag cloudifiers* that can do this and a lot more, I don't know if you're interested in this kind of stuff but if you're just Google for it.

Comment: @animuson: With jQuery you could easily get the width of each tag and order them on the client-side. It'll save you some headaches trying to calculate `strlen * font-char-width` on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting them in a div that is the exact height of the text, then floating them all over the place?

Comment: but then more popular words with bigger fonts won't fit or go into the other tags.