# Java: How to draw images on the smallest possible surface?

Tags: java, image, puzzle, model-fitting

Let's say I have 256 images with an average size of 70x150 (So, size if variable). And I have a `Graphic`-instance (Created from a BufferedImage with a given size) on which I want to draw the images. But I want to draw them at the lowest possible surface. So, not simply in a grid, but really puzzled in each other. But!: they may not overlap each other.

Maybe this something only a human brain can manage.
It is worth asking it, I think....

Thanks in advance,
Martijn

For example:

```
+------++------+
|      ||      |
| img1 || img2 |
|      |+------+
|      |+-----------------+
+------+|                 |
+---+   |                 |
| 3 |   |                 |
|   |   |    img 4        |
+---+   |                 |
        |                 |
        +-----------------+
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking how to find the smallest rectangle in a list of rectangle? Or howw to actually draw your example? Or whats the smallest size you can draw with a Graphic instance`?

Comment: I don't know the exact terminology to use, but this problem sounds a lot like a 2D version of the hard drive or memory space management problem: given a new file/data you want to store, where do you put it? Best fit, worst fit, first fit, etc.  Maybe you could read up on that to get some ideas.

Comment: @DGH: Indeed, that is a relevant comparison.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked before:
[What algorithm can be used for packing rectangles of different sizes into the smallest rectangle possible in a fairly optimal way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/algorithm-needed-for-packing-rectangles-in-a-fairly-optimal-way)

A good survey, from a previous answer, is available at:
http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're asking for a solution to a [knapsack problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

There is none optimal algorithm for a Knapsack Problem of arbitrary size, since it's NP-hard problem.

There are plentiful of sub-optimal algorithms:

- Greedy search algorithms.
- Heuristic search space traveling algorithms, such as [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) family
- Stochastic search algorithms, such as [simmulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)