# How to fill width with wrapped controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

In an attempt to waste less screen real-estate, I've used a `StackPanel` to couple a `Label` with its respective `TextBox` twice, then wrapped those within a `WrapPanel`. *(In this example I am only referring to the `Branch` and `Phone` controls.)*

When the screen is large enough, the two `StackPanel` controls are side-by-side and fill the necessary width:

[image: filled width]

When the screen shrinks, the two `StackPanel` controls are correctly wrapped, but leave blank space on the right:

[image: empty width]

Below is the xaml write-up to accomplish what I have thus far. Nevermind the `validatingTextBoxStyle` as it only affects a red outline and error `ToolTip`.

```
<WrapPanel
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Margin="0">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label 
            Content="Branch" 
            Margin="5,3" 
            Width="40"/>
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="textBox"
            Height="24"  
            Margin="5,0,5,5"              
            Style="{StaticResource validatingTextBoxStyle}"
            Text="{Binding BranchNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
            MinWidth="150"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label 
            Content="Phone" 
            Margin="5,3" 
            Width="40"/>
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="phone" 
            TabIndex="2"
            Height="24"  
            Margin="5,0,5,5"              
            Style="{StaticResource validatingTextBoxStyle}"
            Text="{Binding PhoneNumberToSearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
            MinWidth="150"/>
    </StackPanel>

</WrapPanel>
```

I've tried adding a `Grid` layer with `ColumnDefinitions` to resize the two `StackPanel` controls, but that negates the wrapping functionality. I've tried setting their `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`, but saw no change. I've also looked into this similar question on [stretching a WrapPanel's child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004981/3773066), but a `UniformGrid` doesn't fit the situation.

Investigating further, I did note that the `StackPanel` controls are not stretching as I thought they might, as noted below when a background color was added:

[image: background colors added]

Is there a way to stretch these controls to fill the remaining width once they've been wrapped?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this... a WrapPanel says *"draw children at whatever size they want, and place them until one would be cut off, then wrap to a new line"*, so child sizes will always be whatever size they specify as. I think the best you could do is switch to a Grid and set the Grid.Row/Grid.Column of items using a converter or trigger... either if width of two items is greater than width of grid, place on second row, or put in a scrollviewer and if scrollbars visible, put in a separate row. I am not sure the best way for that though.

Comment: @Rachel I was afraid this might be the case.  I'll just have to keep hoping another WPF wizard has some magic up their sleeves still in store for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid instead of WrapPanel if you want to control the widths of the columns. For example this will make the labels width 70 and the text boxes fill the remaining space:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Branch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="branchTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Content="Phone" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="phoneTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```