# WPF WrapPanel, but fills empty space due to different size items?

Tags: wpf, layout

I have a list of "Group" objects, each of which contains a list of "Option" objects, that show up as checkboxes. I want these to be displayed in a condensed fashion automatically without me having to layout the UI manually with something such as a Grid (which is what I've done in the past, and takes a lot of effort).

My groups have varying numbers of options, so the size of the container for the group is not the same across groups. I'm using a WrapPanel, but it leads to a fairly ugly design because each item in the WrapPanel appears to be slotted into the same size container:

[image: App with WrapPanel]

I know I've done this in HTML/CSS/JS, where I can have it automatically condense the unused space. Is there something like this for WPF? My list of options is manually created, but I can add/remove options fairly easily in my code, so I would rather not have to manually recalculate things in a grid view.

I've looked at [Is there any way to occupy blank space in WrapPanel automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843080/is-there-any-way-to-occupy-blank-space-in-wrappanel-automatically), which sounds similar, but the answer to that question does not have an example and I could not figure out what I was actually supposed to change/use in the answer (my attempts using it did not make any difference at all to layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use Horizontal Orientation of WrapPanel, so every row have height as the maximum its element. Your problem isn't free space in the ends of rows, so the solution that you mentioned doesn't work for you. You can try to use Vertical orientation of WrapPanel, your wrappanel' elements look like they have similar width, possible it would look better.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. I didn't even think about doing things vertically...