# Scaling rectangle packing in a square

Tags: packing

I have a square. Then I have a known number of rectangles, varying in widths and heights (tendency to be near square, but not always). I need to pack the rectangles into the square such that a minimum amount of area is wasted in the square. So far, basic.

But additionally, the rectangles can be **scaled**, as well as **rotated**. Their **relative sizes** to one another should change by as little as possible.

With so many degrees of freedom the problem becomes rather fuzzy. Does anyone have links to further reading, or a suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "rectangle packing algorithm" ? There's a post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/algorithm-needed-for-packing-rectangles-in-a-fairly-optimal-way

Comment: @the_lotus Yes. None of them have scaling, which is the crux of this question.

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? I'm working on a similar problem.

Comment: @SebaK I did not. Still need a good solution. I'd probably try simulated annealing, or something, were it acute to solve this myself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update. I have the additional constraint that the output should be deterministic, so that excludes most metaheuristics.