# How to combine varying size images to minimal combined image?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a set of images that have varying resolution (both width and height) and I'm trying to combine the images into one large image. I would like to minimize the width and height of the final combined image, so find an arrangement where max(combined_width, combined_height) is minimal. The images are rectangular and cannot overlap. Is there an algorithm I could use for this?

Illustration of the problem:

[Problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOLta.jpg)

An example set of image sizes (width, height):

(91, 272)
(113, 254)
(82, 237)
(83, 203)
(36, 109)
(67, 192)
(88, 198)
(91, 215)
(126, 264)
(99, 287)
(88, 313)
(38, 63)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What algorithm can be used for packing rectangles of different sizes into the smallest rectangle possible in a fairly optimal way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/what-algorithm-can-be-used-for-packing-rectangles-of-different-sizes-into-the-sm)

Comment: @user3080953 Thanks for the link. In the end, given that the algorithms I could try were either slow with large number of images or suboptimal (a lot of empty space in the final image), I decided to calculate the mean image size and scale all images to that size and then create a simple grid that minimizes the final width and height. It introduces some stretching to the images, but it is ok for my purpose.