# Get X and Y sizes of remaining surface area

Tags: c#, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I have bins that I'm packing components into, but have trouble with components of smaller sizes not "using" the available space in the current bin (so I am creating a new bin when it isn't required).

```
    private bool ComponentFitsInBin(PackedComponent component, Bin bin)
    {
        if (bin.RemainingSurfaceArea - component.GetSurfaceArea() < 0)
            return false;
        if (component.SizeX > bin.SizeX)
            return false;
        if (component.SizeY > bin.SizeY)
            return false;

        if (bin.SizeX - bin.PackedComponents.Sum(p => p.SizeX) <= component.SizeX)
            if (bin.SizeY - bin.PackedComponents.Sum(p => p.SizeY) <= component.SizeY)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

I realize that the last 2 if's with the Sum calculations are causing the problem, but I'm not sure how to better detect my case.

Below is a visual representation of the result for my test case: the small component in the second bin should be inside the first.

[image: second bin's contents should be in the first bin]

The shapes (both bins and components) are always rectangles or squares. The components can be rotated 90 degrees but never anything that causes a diagonal line.

I have a feeling it might be required to store the location of the already-placed components but I don't know how I would go about determining that location.

If I remove the check that I think is causing the problem, I get the following results:

[image]

As you can see the first bin has a component that's falling outside of the bin because the surface area is big enough but not the correct shape (ignore the numbers, they are required for the project and I only just now added them).

Comment: Superficially your logic looks sound to me, so what are the intermediate values here?

Comment: Can we assume that components as well as bins are *rectangles*? Can we *rotate* components?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, all are rectangles/squares (never any other shape). I did want to check if rotating them 90 degrees would fit them in a bin (to further lessen the amount of bins used) but that's just the same rectangle with X and Y swapped.

Comment: The biggest issue is that it's possible for multiple components to fit horizontally next to eachother, so I can't just take the X of the bin and remove the X of a single component (same problem vertically).

Comment: Is this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/what-algorithm-can-be-used-for-packing-rectangles-of-different-sizes-into-the-sm) related to your issue? This looks related to (rectangle) [packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems).

Comment: @evilmandarine I did follow some instructions from the accepted answer there (like going largest components first), but the problem is that there being enough space in the bin doesn't matter if that space isn't as tall and wide as the component. Right now if I go by just surface area alone the components will be placed half over the lower edge of the bin.

Comment: I added an image to show what happens when I don't perform that last check in ComponentFitsInBin.

Comment: So basically your question is only how to fix this function, i.e. given a bin with some available surface remaining and a rectangle-shape component of some shape, does this component fully fit in the bin remaining surface (green in your pictures)? That is in the second example there should be 2 wide rectangles in each bin and the square in the first one? Also once components are placed (ex. if square comes first), can the position change to accommodate other shapes or not?

Comment: Yes you are correct that the second example should be 2 wide in each bin with the square in the first. I did not consider moving the rectangles after the fact, but I don't think that will be necessary (unless it makes a big difference in space used).