# Fitting rectangles together in optimal fashion

Tags: algorithm, packing, bin-packing

I was wondering if anyone knows of any algorithms suited to fitting together N number of rectangles of unknown size into the smallest possible containing rectangle.

By optimal I mean with reducing the amount of white space left over in the resulting containing rectangle.

I would like to use this to generate css sprites from a series of images.

Many Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Why does the containing shape also have to be square? Why can't it be rectangular but not square?

Comment: Good point. I meant rectangle. I'll edit.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=rectangle+packing+algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through [packing images into square texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263932/packing-rectangular-image-data-into-a-square-texture) and [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34536/simon-wittber)'s answer I got to this link http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442299/

I did not check the recipe, but it seems to allow using non-square containers.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you describe is a variant of the "two dimensional bin packing" problem. The only difference is that you have the items and are trying to find the smallest rectangle.

[This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X0100347X) survey article is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to guarantee and optimal solution is to brute force the answer.  This quickly becomes unmanagable for personal computers when you have several rectangles, and allow for the possibility of rotation.

Wikipedia has a good article on packing problem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good description of a fast packing algorithm - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx