# Distributing a set of rectangles vertically to prevent any overlaps in R

Tags: r, algorithm, graphics, geometry, rectangles

I have a set of rectangles (stored as a set of xmin,ymin and xmax,ymax coordinates in an R data frame), some of which overlap, that I would like to plot on a chart and distribute them along the y-axis so that no two rectangles overlap. Their x coordinates must stay preserved; I need to achieve the goal by shifting the rectangles only vertically.

A concrete example:

```
df <- structure(list(xmin = c(67.705914, 6.005184, 66.162244, 87.99481, 
46.082243, 16.280928, 47, 3.4155154, 23.347187, 84.895525, 82.80274, 
16.85878, 4.3557265, 6.625263, 7.626907, 96.220383, 12.115471, 
30.235073, 46.082243, 16.280928, 79.90225, 29.42548, 84.895525, 
23.347184, 3.198581, 7.2832146, 25.539455, 1.695044, 34.425616, 
3.87074, 78.284034, 89.64427, 87.0506, 87.68941, 75.329986, 2.213225, 
3.4155154, 4.6098725, 0.5424367, 80.416396, 12.115471, 6.625263, 
32.722494, 8.344733, 89.64427, 52.48499, 90.12926, 30.235073, 
2.9885126, 8.719267), xmax = c(73.705914, 12.005184, 72.162244, 
93.99481, 52.082243, 22.280928, 53, 9.4155154, 29.347187, 90.895525, 
88.80274, 22.85878, 10.3557265, 12.625263, 13.626907, 102.220383, 
18.115471, 36.235073, 52.082243, 22.280928, 85.90225, 35.42548, 
90.895525, 29.347184, 9.198581, 13.2832146, 31.539455, 7.695044, 
40.425616, 9.87074, 84.284034, 95.64427, 93.0506, 93.68941, 81.329986, 
8.213225, 9.4155154, 10.6098725, 6.5424367, 86.416396, 18.115471, 
12.625263, 38.722494, 14.344733, 95.64427, 58.48499, 96.12926, 
36.235073, 8.9885126, 14.719267), ymin = c(15.6854458039728, 
29.280227138751, 85.6077652217337, 11.1447959143222, 88.6507847970509, 
47.8780668201714, 58.249961106352, 20.7963843697899, 39.1374442773956, 
14.253314246173, 31.2038928836167, 75.406238562994, 90.8407922528565, 
34.3969058783788, 90.0758115822633, 47.8810408921933, 41.9826622904241, 
18.4008825788269, 64.0816967514961, 26.1344753018713, 87.6969580943045, 
29.8031653049004, 25.5889076966207, 24.8832114234653, 65.6939979329678, 
83.7251558885676, 62.3262453418105, 52.1180170583712, 22.2274072090833, 
46.6403205808079, 51.4982774017124, 52.9611597344073, 86.5149513741532, 
8.71673006759099, 73.63580649852, 10.2390589604505, 79.6728413001311, 
27.0399934909858, 17.2084996917785, 28.7198728007395, 27.7845507714287, 
64.8898031132345, 77.518346688506, 11.785758214691, 51.2219947101639, 
55.4683310942946, 59.4959604756725, 15.6990628891733, 53.6174786549635, 
49.4079504426206), ymax = c(17.2907089618675, 31.2234089569328, 
87.3295043521685, 13.2730010425273, 90.8437672531913, 50.9203203412982, 
60.4271762962254, 23.1819265384646, 41.6096664996178, 15.6887703563279, 
34.0475653401924, 77.3496347894091, 93.4576597227361, 37.1520079191952, 
92.2237107419272, 52.1189591078067, 43.7265046549561, 21.6912051594721, 
65.7843994541988, 28.3922072606342, 89.9154454892625, 33.7570368040767, 
27.4828470905601, 26.6122436815298, 69.5273312663012, 86.1164074074011, 
64.1048569740807, 55.1107177882982, 23.6523109318047, 48.9688920093793, 
54.4445139608521, 55.219401492649, 88.3781992374011, 11.2337368703121, 
75.7899915205464, 13.1508236663329, 85.2391063603721, 29.4730210139216, 
20.1518959181936, 33.1198728007395, 30.7228223763669, 66.81402503475, 
79.1315542356758, 13.8413137702466, 52.7337440574224, 57.6201635550276, 
61.8678354756725, 19.1313772996537, 55.6110888786056, 51.560255051839
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax)) + geom_rect(color="black",fill="cyan") + theme_void()
```

results in

[image: The actual output of plotting rectangles]

whereas I would need something like this

[image: The desired output]

Is there a way how to achieve this in R?

I have encountered a few similar posts thorough the web, most notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265986/an-algorithm-to-space-out-overlapping-rectangles), [here](https://mikekling.com/comparing-algorithms-for-dispersing-overlapping-rectangles/), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750377/move-rectangles-so-they-dont-overlap), but none of them seem to solve my problem of distributing rectangles only vertically to prevent overlaps, and in the R language.

What I have tried out of desperation is randomly shifting the rectangles using the `swarmy` function from the `beeswarm` package an checking for overlaps, but this is not usable as with a large number of rectangles, you could wait ages till the random algorithm finds a solution.

**EDIT**

Following the advice given in Dave's answer (any drawing some inspiration from Marcus's answer), I made a working piece of code:

```
library(ggplot2)

#' tests if a rectangle overlaps with any other rectangle from a set of rectangles
#'
#' @param testRect the rectangle to be tested for overlaps (in the form of any structure having the $xmin, $xmax, $ymin, and $ymax attributes)
#' @param rectList a data frame with the xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax columns containing the set of rectangles to test the overlaps with
#' @returns a Boolean value, TRUE if there any any overlaps, FALSE if there are not
#' 
overlaps_any <- function(testRect, rectList) {
  if(nrow(rectList)==0) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  for (r in 1:nrow(rectList)) {
    # If rectangle has area 0, no overlap
    if (testRect$xmin == testRect$xmax || testRect$ymax == testRect$ymin || rectList[r,"xmin"] == rectList[r,"xmax"] || rectList[r,"ymax"] == rectList[r,"ymin"]) {
      next
    }
    
    # If one rectangle is on the left side of the other
    if (testRect$xmin > rectList[r,"xmax"] || rectList[r,"xmin"] > testRect$xmax) {
      next
    }
    
    # If one rectangle is above the other
    if (testRect$ymin > rectList[r,"ymax"] || rectList[r,"ymin"] > testRect$ymax) {
      next
    }
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

# Create an empty data frame
df.new <- data.frame()

# Iterate over each row of the original data frame
for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  # Select the rectangle from the original data frame
  testRect <- df[r,]
  
  # Calculate the height of the rectangle
  rect_height <- testRect$ymax - testRect$ymin
  
  # Set the minimum y-coordinate of the rectangle to 0
  testRect$ymin <- 0
  
  # Set the maximum y-coordinate of the rectangle based on the height
  testRect$ymax <- testRect$ymin + rect_height
  
  # Check if the rectangle overlaps with any existing rectangles in the new data frame
  while(overlaps_any(testRect, df.new)) {
    # Increment the y-coordinates of the rectangle by 1 to avoid overlap
    testRect$ymin <- testRect$ymin + 1
    testRect$ymax <- testRect$ymax + 1
  }
  
  # Append the updated rectangle to the new data frame
  df.new <- rbind(df.new, testRect)
}

# Plot the rectangles using ggplot
print(
  ggplot(df.new, aes(
    xmin = xmin,
    xmax = xmax,
    ymin = ymin,
    ymax = ymax
  )) +
    geom_rect(color = "black", fill = "cyan") + coord_fixed() + theme_void()
)
```

Result:

[image: Rectangles after the reordering]

Comment: Do you have a way of picking the best between multiple valid solutions?

Comment: @Dave No, any valid solution will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all valid solutions are equally good, we can use something dead simple.

Pick any rectangle to be your first rectangle, and shift it vertically so the smaller y-coord is at zero.

Repeatedly do the following:

- pick any rectangle and call it 'cur', and lets call the prior rectangle placed 'pri'
- delta = pri.y_max - cur.y_min
- cur.y_min = cur.y_min + delta
- cur.y_max = cur.y_max + delta
- We've now shifted the cur rectangle to be immediately above the prior rectangle placed.
- repeat

This won't be as compact as it could be (in most cases) and won't preserve relative vertical positioning, but is fast and gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a function that will find the max overlap for any given rectangle (`testRect`) against a list of all rectangles (`rectList`).

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

MaxYOverlap <- function(testRect, rectList) {
  
  overlaps <- rectList |> 
    # filter for potentially overlapping rectangles,
    # which will include the test rectangle itself
    filter(
      xmin <= testRect$xmax, 
      xmax >= testRect$xmin,
      ymin <= testRect$ymax,
      ymax >= testRect$ymin,
      # avoid duplicates by searching only above
      ymax >= testRect$ymax
    ) |> 
    mutate(
      yoverlap = testRect$ymax - ymin
    ) 

  if(NROW(overlaps) > 1){
    # will overlap perfectly with itself, so take second greatest
    overlaps |> 
      arrange(-yoverlap) |> 
      slice(2) |> 
      pluck("yoverlap")
  } else {
    # ignore if it only overlaps with itself
    0
  }
  
}
```

Then starting from the bottom, progressively shift the rectangles by the cumulative amount of overlap up until that rectangle's position (which have been ordered bottom to top)

```
# ensure applying shifts from bottom up
df <- df |>
  arrange(ymax)

df_jittered <- df |> 
  mutate(
    maxOverlap = pmap_dbl(df, \(...) MaxYOverlap(data.frame(...), rectList = df)),
    # shift by additional 100% to create visual separation
    cumShift = cumsum(maxOverlap) * 5,
    ymin = ymin + lag(cumShift, default = 0),
    ymax = ymax + lag(cumShift, default = 0)
  )
```

You could get fancy and only apply the shifts to the rectangles directly above two overlapping ones, but I'll that as an exercise to the reader :-)
[image: jittered rectangles]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a R package to solve this but in general your question could pointing to *"Computational Geometry Algorithms"*  in the field of *"Point/Polygon-Feature Label Placement"* if you assume or imagine, that your frames are the extent some text labels with a root point may be in the center or the lower left corner of the shown rectangle (...see image below) .

Example from [*Christensen, Marks, Schieber: "An Empirical Study of Algorithms
for Point-Feature Label Placement"*](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Eshieber/Biblio/Papers/tog-final.pdf)

[image]

So the buzzwords to internet searches in this field could be:

- [Automatic label placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement)
- [Balanced Point-Feature Label Placement Algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221079386_Balance_Algorithm_for_Point-Feature_Label_Placement_Problem)
- [Labeling Algorithm](https://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/labeling.pdf)
- [Polygon-Feature Label Placement Algorithm](https://rgeos.r-forge.r-project.org/reference/labelpt.html)

In common the algorithms tries to handle a optimization problem, to move the rectangles along or around rule based paths form the start or root point with the following conditions:

1. The frames should not to overlap each other.
2. The extent of the resulting frame ensemble should span a minimal area around the complete root point ensemble.
3. Optionally maintenance of the *"spatial order"* could be demanded (*"Constraint Labeling Algorithm"*).

I have not tested this but R the package `rgeos` with the function [`polygonsLabel(...)`](https://rgeos.r-forge.r-project.org/reference/labelpt.html) some of your requested features looks promising and the inner functionality could be investigated to exchange the text driven input with the frames.